# What's the difference between custom class and file's owner setting in xib file?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

In a custom xib file, what's the difference between the two following setting methods shown in the images below?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please check this link : 
[What is the File's Owner (in Interface builder)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251370/what-is-the-files-owner-in-interface-builder)
[confused difference between Custom Class for an Object and for the File's Owner and steps via IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150713/confused-difference-between-custom-class-for-an-object-and-for-the-files-owner)

in first screen shot :  you should set the custom class of your View .

and in the second screen shot  (`files owner`) you can Set the file's owner to your UIView subclass so that you can connect outlets to it

Comment: Thank you, I got it from your answer! 

Comment: I still cannot figure it out from your explanation, I have a subclass of `UITableViewCell` with certain customization functions, however I've tested that no matter where I assign this subclass, as File's Owner or Custom Class, there is no difference at all, I cannot set and connect outlets regardless the places. Even I set to both places it still behaved the exactly the same.

Comment: @Mazen WDM that you can't find a difference  ?

Comment: It works even if I set the class to the UIView, not the file owner. I can connect an outlet to a UILabel and edit its contents. I can't find any difference between setting the class to the file's owner vs to the view.

Answer (score 0):

When you add custom `UIView` with `XIB` you init this custom view in some `UIViewController` and write:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CardView", bundle: nil)
let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! CardView
```

File's owner (in `withOwner:` parameter) this is usually owner is a ViewController where you add your custom 
`UIView`