# Difference between File Owner and Custom Class in XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I'm a bit confused between the difference of using `File Owner` and `Custom Class` when I create a `Xib` into Xcode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between custom class and file's owner setting in xib file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894563/whats-the-difference-between-custom-class-and-files-owner-setting-in-xib-file)

Comment: Maybe this help you [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15265241/9287710)