# Swift create Custom View from Nib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, nib

I try to implement Custom Loader View with Nib file. But I get an error
in `loadViewFromNib()` at

```
return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView.
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee6f3df98)

```
open class LoaderView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var loaderImage: UIImageView!    
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

func xibSetup() {
    contentView = loadViewFromNib()
    contentView.frame = bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(contentView)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "LoaderView", bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
}
}
```

I call this loader in VC in `viewDidLoad()` as

```
let loader = LoaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
view.addSubview(loader)
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure You have set class `LoaderView`  in XIB's FilesOwner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine there is no recursion

Please make sure you have

1) Double check your IBOUtlet connection

2) Added Your class in **File's Owner**

---

[image]

[image]

I have created This same as your code

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    let nibName = "CustomView"
    @IBOutlet var view : UIView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetUp()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetUp()
    }

    func xibSetUp() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

    }

}
```

Have look at output

[image]

Comment: I am sure about that the IBOutlet and Xib connection in Files Owner. Your code is same. But still not working. I dont use storyboard for VC. Is there any problem at there ?.

Comment: @AliUral Make sure your xib is added In target membership (Build phase check copy bundle resource). Also Clean derived data + clean project or restart xcode

Comment: I added an image

Comment: @AliUral That's wrong !! , Remove Loader from there and add to File's owner  , Check yellow box top on it where file's owner written

Comment: Thanks Dude . The problem is solved. But can you explain why we put in there. Normally when I create a Xib File , I decleare class name from Element not File's Owner. Is it wrong ?

Comment: @AliUral Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150713/confused-difference-between-custom-class-for-an-object-and-for-the-files-owner

Comment: Thanks bro. I give ur star :)

Answer (score 2):

You have recursion in

```
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}
```

You call `loadViewFromNib()` in `xibSetup()`, it call `UINib(nibName: "LoaderView", bundle: bundle)`, that call `required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`

[developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8)

Comment: That's not true

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya Why? Most likely, the hierarchy of views is broken.

Comment: Nope `public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` will call when it is being initiated from storyboard  like when you have view in storyboard and assign a class LoaderView.   And Important thing is `instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)` will never call   `public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`